# How to output list of strings into .csv-file with several columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a scraper which puts all swedish parliament members into a .csv file with several columns.

I've managed to get the list of names as seen below. I'm having problems with splitting the strings into last names, first names and party, and then writing a .csv file with these three columns, how do I do that?

Code:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter- 
partier/").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"})

for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"}):
    cleanednames = span.text.strip()
    print(cleanednames)
```

Output:

```
Acketoft, Tina (L)
Adaktusson, Lars (KD)
Ahlberg, Ann-Christin (S)
Akhondi, Alireza (C)
Ali-Elmi, Leila (MP)
Alm Ericson, Janine (MP)
...
```

Comment: "Having a little trouble" is not a problem specification.  *What* trouble are you having?  You've apparently separated the three fields quite well.  From here, it *should* be a simple matter of using the `csv` package to write your file, no?

Comment: Try `cleanednames.replace(',', '').split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet using the pandas library to write a csv. From each fellow-name span we extract the last name, first name, and party, and append the 3 strings as a list to a list. Then we cast that list of lists to a pandas dataframe and write it to csv.

```
import urllib
import bs4 as bs 
import pandas as pd
source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-partier/").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"})

list_of_mps = []

for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"}):
    cleanednames = span.text.strip()
    split_name = cleanednames.split(',')
    last_name = split_name[0]
    first_name_and_party=split_name[1].strip()
    first_name=' '.join(first_name_and_party.split(' ')[:-1])
    party=first_name_and_party.split(' ')[-1]
    list_of_mps.append([last_name,first_name,party])
pd.DataFrame(list_of_mps,columns = ['last_name','first_name','party']).to_csv('names_parties')
```

Comment: Pandas is overkill for this. The `csv` module should be more than enough https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer.

Answer (score 0):

With the output that you have shown, you can add this to a csv file in a loop.

take a empty list and append the fields to it rather printing. see below example.

```
data = []

for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"}):
    cleanednames = span.text.strip()
    data.append(cleanednames)  #fields are appended to list rather printing
```

Now with the list you can extract the `last_name` , `first_name` , `party` and write it to a csv file. see below example to write to csv.

```
with open("result.csv", "w") as stream:
    feildnames = ["Last_Name","First_Name","Party"]
    var = csv.DictWriter(stream, fieldnames=feildnames)
    var.writeheader()
    for item in data:
        last_name, First_name, party = item.split()  #splitting data in 3 fields
        last_name = last_name.replace(",","")  #removing ',' from last name
        party = party.replace("(","").replace(")","")  #removing "()" from party
        var.writerow({"Last_Name": last_name,"First_Name": First_name, "Party": party})  #writing to csv row
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment of the previous, pandas is overkill. Using csv instead, we have:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
import csv

source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.riksdagen.se/sv/ledamoter-partier/").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

names = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"})
with open("csv-name.csv", 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for span in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "fellow-name"}):
        cleanednames = span.text.strip()
        lname, rest = cleanednames.split(", ")
        rest = rest.split(" ")
        party = rest[-1]
        fname = " ".join(rest[:-1])
        writer.writerow([lname, fname, party])
```

What's going on in the code: we first split by comma; everything before the comma is a last name. We then split by space, and we know the last thing will be the party. Finally, what's left over is the first name.